# One-liner version of this function? (Ruby 1.8.6)

Tags: ruby, function

In the version of Ruby i'm using, (1.8.6 - don't ask), the Hash class doesn't define the `Hash#hash` method, which means that calling `uniq` on an array of hashes doesn't test whether the content is the same - it tests whether the objects are the same (using the default base Object#hash method).

To get around this, I can use `include?`, like so:

```
hashes = <a big list of hashes>
uniq_hashes = []
hashes.each do |hash|
  unless uniq_hashes.include?(hash)
    uniq_hashes << hash
  end
end;uniq_hashes.size
```

Can anyone think of a way to condense this into a one-line method?

Comment: If `hashes` is array then `hashes.uniq` will do.

Comment: @maximusツ Not in Ruby 1.8.6. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290871/ruby-1-8-6-arrayuniq-not-removing-duplicate-hashes

Comment: What about implementing `Hash#hash` and `Hash#eql?` so you can just use `uniq`?

Comment: @Stefan that's going to be my next question! I just wondered about a neater version of the above.

Comment: @MaxWilliams take a look at [`backports/1.8.7/hash/hash.rb`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/1.8.7/hash/hash.rb) from Marc-André Lafortune's [Backports Library](https://github.com/marcandre/backports).

Comment: @Stefan ah that's brilliant, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `include?` to check if each hash matches a previously-examined hash, one can speed things up by making use of a set. Recall that a set is implemented with a hash under the covers, which explains why lookups are so fast.

```
require 'set'

def uniq_hashes(arr)
  st = Set.new
  arr.select { |h| st.add?(h) }
end

uniq_hashes [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { b: 2, a: 1 }, { a: 1, c: 2 }]
  #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:a=>1, :c=>2}]
```

See [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F).

Comment: Wow, I just benchmarked that with an array of 88,000 large hashes, and it's MUCH faster than the answer I marked as correct already by @SebastiánPalma.  That's to be expected I guess since the number of ops in the `include?` approach will grow exponentially with the array size.  I've never really used sets before, i'll look into them a bit.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use each_with_object?

```
hashes = [{title: 'a'}, {title: 'b'}, {title: 'c'}, {title: 'a'}]
p hashes.each_with_object([]) { |el, array| array << el unless array.include? el }.size
# 3
```

Comment: That's great, I'd not seen `each_with_object` before - handy!

Comment: Sorry, I just took the correct status off this and gave it to @CarySwoveland since his answer (not stricly one line, but easily changed to one line) runs in a tiny fraction of the time, for large arrays.  Sorry if that's a breach of SE protocol!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> hashes = <a big list of hashes>
> uniq_hashes = []
> hashes.each do |hash|
>   unless uniq_hashes.include?(hash)
>     uniq_hashes << hash
>   end
> end;uniq_hashes.size
> ```
>
> Can anyone think of a way to condense this into a one-line method?

Easy:

```
hashes = <a big list of hashes>; uniq_hashes = []; hashes.each do |hash| unless uniq_hashes.include?(hash) then uniq_hashes << hash end end;uniq_hashes.size
```

In fact, you can *always* condense *any* Ruby code into one line, since newlines are completely optional. Newlines can always be replaced with either semicolons, separator keywords, or just nothing.